How to unlock and open locked door in the Clock Tower?
There's a door that seems to be locked in the clock tower:

I've tried different things and tried looking for clues, but it's not obvious on how to open the door and get into the room.
How can this door be opened?

If you found the answer useful, please consider accepting it

To open the locked doors in the Clock Tower:

Watch the pendulum and wait for it to reach the corresponding icon.
Cast Arresto Momentum or Glacius on the pendulum to slow its movement.
Once it has stopped, the bars on the door will open for a short period of time.
If you missed your chance, use Confringo (or Incendio if you're close) to thaw the pendulum.


Owl

Before opening the owl door, make sure you've got an invisibility potion or a Disillusionment spell equipped due to the eyeball chests inside the room. To access it, take the stairs behind the locked door and head to the first floor.

Source, Gfinity Esports.
